# Fingerprint option is not shown in lenovo thinkpad e14

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, 20.10, fingerprint-reader, user-profile

i have this hardware in my system
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:55a4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device

please anyone tell me how to enable fingerprint in my lenovo thinkpad e14
my ubuntu version is 20.10

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1885167

Answer (score 1):

It is not compatible yet, but good folks are working on it. There is long thread about it https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/376
And there is discord server with all the news on all devices: https://discord.gg/K4rFkXqg